# Inequality of exponential

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

Trying to show $$\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-y}}{y-x}\leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-x}+e^{-y})$$ I tried working with $y>x$, and the case $y-x\geq2$ was trivial. But I guess this isn't useful. Using the mean value theorem and writing the problem as $\frac{e^y-e^x}{y-x}\leq\frac{1}{2}(e^y+e^x)$ I get that exists a $c\in(x,y)$ s.t. $\frac{e^y-e^x}{y-x}=e^c$ but I can't get the inequality. In other hand, $e^x$ is convex, so $\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}+e^{y})\geq e^{\frac{x+y}{2}}$. Ought I try to show $e^{\frac{x+y}{2}}\geq e^c$ ?

Comment: You mean $e^y$ instead of $x^y$ in the last line, right?

Comment: Thanks. Fixed..

Comment: Hint: it's pure 
$\operatorname{LM}(a,b)\le \operatorname{AM}(a,b)$ inequality for
$a=\exp(-x),\, b=\exp(-y)$,
where $\operatorname{LM}(a,b)=\frac{a-b}{\ln(a)-\ln(b)}$,
[Logarithmic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean),
and $\operatorname{AM}(a,b)=\frac{a+b}2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $e^{-x}$ is convex, you have $$e^{-tx-(1-t)y}\le t\,e^{-x}+(1-t)\,e^{-y}$$ for $t\in[0,1]$. Now integrate both sides over $t$ from $0$ to $1$, and you get exactly your inequality.

Answer (score 0):

As

$$F(x,y) = -\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-y}}{y-x}+\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x}+x^{-y})$$ is symmetric in $x,y$, we can suppose $y\ge x$. We have to prove that

$$(y-x)e^x F(x,y)=-(1-e^{-(y-x)})+\frac{y-x}{2}(1+e^{-(y-x)})$$ is non negative for $y \ge x$.

This is equivalent to prove that

$$f(x)=-(e^x-1)+\frac{x}{2}(e^x +1)$$ is non negative for $x \ge 0$.

$$f^\prime(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-e^x+xe^x\right), \, f^{\prime\prime}(x)=\frac{xe^x}{2}\ge 0.$$

As $f^\prime(0)=0$, $f^\prime$ is non negative, $f $ non decreasing and as $f(0)=0$ we get the desired conclusion.

Comment: I made a mistake. I fixed it already. Sorry.